# How to set a sampling frequency of 10ksps AD7606 through Aurdino?

Tags: arduino-uno, adc

This is the code for interfacing AD7606 with arduino. This code is working and I am able to read all the 8 channels. But my requirement is to set 10ksps.

```
#include <SPI.h>

uint32_t startTime, elapsedTime, old_res;
#define SCALE_FACTOR 0.000152587890625

#define BUSY 32               // you can use any digital pin   
 
#define START_CONVERSION 34   // you can use any digital pin    
#define CHIP_SELECT 53        // SPI CS     
#define D7_out 50             // SPI MISO there is no need to use MOSI port with the ad7606 
#define RD 52                 // SPI SCLK 

#define TOTAL_RAW_BYTES 16
SPISettings _spiSettings;

int bytesToRead = TOTAL_RAW_BYTES;
byte raw[TOTAL_RAW_BYTES];
uint16_t parsed[8];


//--------------SETUP-UP---------------------------
void setup()
{
  initial();
  Serial.begin(2000000);
  while(!Serial){} // wait for usb connection
  SPI.begin();
}
//---------------LOOP--------------------------
void loop()
{
  startTime = micros();  
  readData();
  elapsedTime = micros() - startTime; 
  if (elapsedTime != old_res) 
  {
    Serial.print("Conversion time:\t");
    Serial.print(elapsedTime);
    Serial.println(" microseconds");
    old_res = elapsedTime;
  }  
  parseRawBytes();

  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    Serial.print((float)parsed[i] * SCALE_FACTOR, 5);
    Serial.print(",");
  }
 
  Serial.print("\r\n");
}
//-----------------------------------------
void initial()
{
  pinMode(BUSY, INPUT);
 
  pinMode(START_CONVERSION, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(CHIP_SELECT, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(D7_out, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RD, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(START_CONVERSION, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(CHIP_SELECT, HIGH);

}
//-----------------------------------------
void parseRawBytes() {
  for(int i = 0; i<(sizeof(parsed) / sizeof(int));i++)
    {
      parsed[i] = (raw[i*2] << 8) + raw[(i*2)+1];
    }
}
//-----------------------------------------

//-----------------------------------------
void conversionPulse(uint8_t port)
{
  digitalWrite(port, LOW);
//  delayMicroseconds(1);
  digitalWrite(port, HIGH);  
}
//-----------------------------------------
/*
1- start conversion START_CONVERSION HIGH
2- wait until the busy is LOW again 
3- put the CS to LOW
4- Read a byte from the SPI 
*/
void readData()
{
  conversionPulse(START_CONVERSION);
  while (digitalRead(BUSY) == HIGH) {
  //  delayMicroseconds(1);
  }
  SPI.beginTransaction(_spiSettings);
  digitalWrite(CHIP_SELECT, LOW);
  while (bytesToRead > 0) {
    raw[TOTAL_RAW_BYTES - bytesToRead] = SPI.transfer(0x00);
    bytesToRead--;
  }
  digitalWrite(CHIP_SELECT, HIGH);
  SPI.endTransaction();

  bytesToRead = TOTAL_RAW_BYTES;
}
//-----------------------------------------
```

Comment: What speed does it do now?

Comment: Hi Rohit Gupta, Now i am getting a sampling frequency of 1.8ksps,i checked this sampling frequency (start conversion signal) through dso.

Comment: Please format your code, this is very hard to read.

Comment: @PMF Hi PMF Please Refer I updated the code

Comment: I'm not sure about the capabilities of the ADC, but a quick estimate suggests this could be hard. An Arduino UNO has a clock frequency of 16 Mhz, requiring a 10kHz sampling rate would require that a single loop does not take more than 1600 clock cycles. Probably possible, but only with optimized code (e.g., remove unnecessary output)

Comment: Thank u for your response dear PMF